# custom exceptions when rescued gives a name error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, rescue, raise

I am trying to raise myExceptions in a service in rails.

But when i rescue with specific name of exception it gives me a nameError for the exception called.

```
status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "#<NameError: uninitialized constant Api::V1::UsersController::CustomExceptions>",
"traces": {
```

**Exceptions File:**

```
module CustomExceptions
  class EmptyObject < StandardError; end
  class WrongParams < StandardError; end
  class Unauthorized < StandardError; end
end
```

**Exception Raised:**

```
class UsersService
class << self
    include AuthenticationHelper
    def find_users(current_user, query_params)          
        users = User.where(some query)
        if users.count > 0
            users
        else
            raise CustomExceptions::EmptyObject, "empty user object returned"
        end
    end
end
end
```

**rescue in controller:**

```
 rescue CustomExceptions::EmptyObject => error
  render json: {error: 'No users found'}, status: 404
end
```

Comment: even if resue just with exception name, it still give me error

Comment: Where did you call `UsersService#find_users`?

Comment: in the controller method, after begin

Comment: Where is the `CustomExceptions` placed at?

Comment: in a folder under app/exceptions/exceptions.rb

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: when i see a gem's exception file. it is named exceptions.rb. but the module name is gemName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you define `CustomExceptions`, so Rails expect you to define that class in file `custom_exceptions.rb`.

In order to call `CustomExceptions`, you should rename the filename.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your namespaces are a little confused. One way to make sure you're using the top namespace and stop it from looking in `UserService` for your exception is to use `::` to explicitly say you want to use the top level:

```
raise ::CustomExceptions::EmptyObject, "empty user object returned"
```